# Which User will be invoking SQL Server Agent Job when using a Windows Task Scheduler to automate the Job to run daily?

Tags: sql-server, windows, scheduled-tasks, sql-server-job

I am using SQL Server 2008 to create a job to calculate some values from an external db and store to another db table. A task scheduler has been created for automating this to run daily and update results to the 2nd table. The job is getting failed with SQL message ID 3621 and severity 14. I googled this message id and got to know that it is due to insufficient privileges for the user.

By default which user will be invoking the SQL job by the task scheduler?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you open the Task properties, you can see what account it is running as:

[image]